# GnuPlot: plot tab separated file based on header entry

Tags: gnuplot

I have a .dat file whose structure is:

```
# Solver information
# Time          U_solver        Ux_initial      Ux_final        Ux_iters        Uy_initial      Uy_final        Uy_iters        U_converged     p_rgh_solver    p_rgh_initial   p_rgh_final     p_rgh_iters     p_rgh_converged
1               smoothSolver    1.000000e+00    9.970980e-02    3   1.000000e+00    7.695910e-02    2   false   GAMGPCG 1.000000e+00    1.344030e-03    2   true
2               smoothSolver    4.692880e-01    2.897640e-02    4   3.109600e-01    1.677980e-02    4   false   GAMGPCG 5.659830e-02    7.100450e-05    2   true
3               smoothSolver    3.224570e-01    2.001160e-02    4   1.225150e-01    6.679510e-03    4   false   GAMGPCG 2.845850e-02    1.661910e-05    2   true
4               smoothSolver    2.448820e-01    1.577350e-02    4   6.852310e-02    3.929980e-03    4   false   GAMGPCG 1.871320e-02    1.306270e-05    2   true
5               smoothSolver    1.966380e-01    1.299020e-02    4   4.082900e-02    2.417220e-03    4   false   GAMGPCG 1.366140e-02    8.455600e-06    2   true
6               smoothSolver    1.644830e-01    1.105430e-02    4   2.524760e-02    1.518770e-03    4   false   GAMGPCG 1.051720e-02    5.429050e-06    2   true
7               smoothSolver    1.410070e-01    9.587650e-03    4   1.614980e-02    9.668240e-04    4   false   GAMGPCG 8.530880e-03    3.920410e-06    2   true
8               smoothSolver    1.230200e-01    8.430390e-03    4   1.108410e-02    6.364510e-04    4   false   GAMGPCG 7.317530e-03    3.798000e-06    2   true
9               smoothSolver    1.084740e-01    7.477240e-03    4   8.517250e-03    4.553620e-04    4   false   GAMGPCG 6.441480e-03    3.981460e-06    2   true
10              smoothSolver    9.651470e-02    6.683950e-03    4   7.464690e-03    3.778350e-04    4   false   GAMGPCG 5.702950e-03    3.980550e-06    2   true
11              smoothSolver    8.635920e-02    6.003360e-03    4   7.318430e-03    7.252650e-04    3   false   GAMGPCG 5.075390e-03    3.904680e-06    2   true
12              smoothSolver    7.764280e-02    5.414310e-03    4   7.463720e-03    7.428540e-04    3   false   GAMGPCG 4.520690e-03    3.631550e-06    2   true
13              smoothSolver    7.003640e-02    4.896810e-03    4   7.639310e-03    3.775700e-04    4   false   GAMGPCG
```

I would like to plot every *name*_initial with gnuplot and keep the header name (Ux_initial, Uy_initial, etc...)

If there anyway to do this?

I do not have experience with gnuplot, so I am stuck ...

Comment: You have more headers than data fields. Is your data example correct?

Comment: It has more lines, this was just not to spam the post

Comment: No, I mean columns...  thanks for the edit. The line 13 is still uncomplete... but doesn't matter...

Comment: The number of columns should be Ok

Comment: Is the file space or tab separated?

Comment: The file is tab separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are lucky, that your data is tab separated. With space separated I wouldn't have a simple solution.
The special thing with your data is that your headerline is commented. The standard comment character in gnuplot is `#` and hence these lines will be ignored.
You have to:

- `set datafile commentschars ""`, i.e. no commented lines
- skip one line `skip 1`
- use `'# Time'` for selecting the column (or you could use the number `1` instead).
- `set key noenhanced` to print the underscore in the legend correctly

**Code:**

```
### plot commented headerline
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Solver information
# Time  U_solver    Ux_initial  Ux_final    Ux_iters    Uy_initial  Uy_final    Uy_iters    U_converged p_rgh_solver    p_rgh_initial   p_rgh_final p_rgh_iters p_rgh_converged
1   smoothSolver    1.00E+00    9.97E-02    3   1.00E+00    7.70E-02    2   FALSE   GAMGPCG 1.00E+00    1.34E-03    2   TRUE
2   smoothSolver    4.69E-01    2.90E-02    4   3.11E-01    1.68E-02    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 5.66E-02    7.10E-05    2   TRUE
3   smoothSolver    3.22E-01    2.00E-02    4   1.23E-01    6.68E-03    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 2.85E-02    1.66E-05    2   TRUE
4   smoothSolver    2.45E-01    1.58E-02    4   6.85E-02    3.93E-03    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 1.87E-02    1.31E-05    2   TRUE
5   smoothSolver    1.97E-01    1.30E-02    4   4.08E-02    2.42E-03    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 1.37E-02    8.46E-06    2   TRUE
6   smoothSolver    1.64E-01    1.11E-02    4   2.52E-02    1.52E-03    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 1.05E-02    5.43E-06    2   TRUE
7   smoothSolver    1.41E-01    9.59E-03    4   1.61E-02    9.67E-04    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 8.53E-03    3.92E-06    2   TRUE
8   smoothSolver    1.23E-01    8.43E-03    4   1.11E-02    6.36E-04    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 7.32E-03    3.80E-06    2   TRUE
9   smoothSolver    1.08E-01    7.48E-03    4   8.52E-03    4.55E-04    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 6.44E-03    3.98E-06    2   TRUE
10  smoothSolver    9.65E-02    6.68E-03    4   7.46E-03    3.78E-04    4   FALSE   GAMGPCG 5.70E-03    3.98E-06    2   TRUE
11  smoothSolver    8.64E-02    6.00E-03    4   7.32E-03    7.25E-04    3   FALSE   GAMGPCG 5.08E-03    3.90E-06    2   TRUE
12  smoothSolver    7.76E-02    5.41E-03    4   7.46E-03    7.43E-04    3   FALSE   GAMGPCG 4.52E-03    3.63E-06    2   TRUE
EOD

set datafile commentschars ""
set datafile separator tab
set key noenhanced

plot $Data u "# Time":"Ux_initial"    skip 1 w lp pt 7 ti columnheader, \
        '' u "# Time":"Uy_initial"    skip 1 w lp pt 7 ti columnheader, \
        '' u "# Time":"p_rgh_initial" skip 1 w lp pt 7 ti columnheader
        
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

The following would be even shorter and gives the same result.

```
myHeaders = 'Ux_initial Uy_initial p_rgh_initial'

plot for [i=1:words(myHeaders)] $Data u "# Time":word(myHeaders,i) skip 1 w lp pt 7 ti columnheader
```

Probably (not 100% sure, let me know if it works or not), in Linux you could use the system command (check `help system`) or backquoting (check `help backquotes`).

```
myHeaders = system("head myFile.dat | grep -o '[^ ]*_initial[^ ]*'")

plot for [i=1:words(myHeaders)] 'myFile.dat' u "# Time":word(myHeaders,i) skip 1 w lp pt 7 ti columnheader
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just an additional question, is it possible to pass the name of the column as argument? If I use `head myFile.dat | grep -o '[^ ]*_inital[^ ]*' ` . I will get the column names to plot which can then be used to plot. Is this possible?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira I'm not sure... I'm not using Linux. How will you have the column names  available in gnuplot? As string variable, e.g. like `myHeaders = 'Ux_initial Uy_initial p_rgh_initial'` ?

Answer (score 0):

So,

I placed everything in an executable file called plotResidual. The code is:

```
filename=$1

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set datafile commentschars ""
    set datafile separator tab
    set key noenhanced
    set logscale y
    set title 'Residuals'
    set ylabel 'Residual'
    set xlabel 'Iteration'
    myHeaders = system("head $filename | grep -o '[^ ]*_initial[^ ]*'")
    plot for [i=1:words(myHeaders)] '$filename' u "# Time":word(myHeaders,i) skip 1 w l ti columnheader 
EOFMarker
```

This way the user will call
`plotResidual myFile.dat` and it will plot accordingly.